# Anyone have a suggested problems list for "Mathematical Proofs A transition to Advanced Mathematics"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, logic, reference-request

Like the title says, I am looking for recommend problem sets for the third edition of "Mathematical Proofs, A transition to Advanced Mathematics" by Chartand, Polimeni and Zhang.

I have the third edition, which is important to note because the question number varies quite drastically from edition to edition. If any has taken a course with this book and could post their old Home Work problem sets, I would really appreciate it.

I did a cursory google search, but the courses I found with posted problem numbers either used a different edition, or did not post the edition. I apologize for the tags, this book covers an introductory amount to a wide variety of subjects, and I wasn't exactly sure what to put.

Comment: Consider [Math Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: oh thank you,  that does sound more relevant

Comment: Check out the problem sets posted [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~gor/Math220_2016/math220_common.html).

Comment: For absolute beginners, you might consider the worked examples and exercises in the tutorial that comes with DC Proof freeware (downloadable at my homepage http://www.dcproof.com ) Click on Features for a list of 13 worked examples. Exercises with full solutions are included for each of these examples. More advanced topics at my math blog http://dcproof.wordpress.com/

Comment: Thanks Prism, that is exactly what I was looking for! If you want to post it as the solution , I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Done! Btw, I didn't get this notification from the system. For the future reference, you may want to write @Prism so the system pings me.

Comment: @Chair: Don't waste your time with Dan's stuff; I've looked at it and it is useless for real mathematics.

Comment: @user21820: yeah I have ended up just working all the odd problems. They seem to span most important topics. Thanks, for the heads up though!

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply somehow. Anyway if you have any mathematics inquiries feel free to ask me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77161/basic-mathematics)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the problem sets posted [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/%7Egor/Math220_2016/math220_common.html).